# How to capture USB traffic using Wireshark in linux CLI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, wireshark

I've found (hopefully) all I need in order to setup Wireshark and `usbmon` kernel module - including allowing a non-root user to capture USB traffic: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html

However, when it comes to trying it all together - not a single resource on SE or Google has an example of a command line to start capture and dump it to a file that I can open in GUI and analyze.

Comment: Wireshark has an [USB manual/documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) maybe is that what you looking for?

Comment: @djdomi I'm afraid I can't find an example of a terminal command to start capture there...

Comment: Here is another useful link that covers the topics mentioned in the original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054437/how-to-install-wireshark-on-linux-and-capture-usb-traffic

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's `tshark` command in charge of capturing stuff from the command line.
First, we need to identify the device we want to capture. Use `tshark -D`

```
$ tshark -D
1. enp1s0
2. lo (Loopback)
3. any
4. bluetooth-monitor
5. nflog
6. nfqueue
7. bluetooth0
8. usbmon0
9. bluetooth1
10. usbmon1
11. usbmon2
12. ciscodump (Cisco remote capture)
13. dpauxmon (DisplayPort AUX channel monitor capture)
14. randpkt (Random packet generator)
15. sdjournal (systemd Journal Export)
16. sshdump (SSH remote capture)
17. udpdump (UDP Listener remote capture)
```

By trial and error, we find that it's device #10 we are interested in capturing, so we run:

```
$ tshark -i 10
Capturing on 'usbmon1'
    1   0.000000         host → 1.2.0        USB 64 GET DESCRIPTOR Request DEVICE
    2   0.000160        1.2.0 → host         USB 82 GET DESCRIPTOR Response DEVICE
```

NOTE: `tshark -i usbmon1` also works.

Use `-c [number]` to limit the number of rows, and `-w [out file name].pcap` to save the capture in `pcap` format that can be imported into Wireshark GUI.

```
$ tshark -c 100 -i 10 -w usbmon1-dump.pcap
```